# Woocommerce Product Price 3 decimals, all Other Prices 2 Decimals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Hello to all!**
I'm new here and already have my first question.
i have a woocommerce project where i need the single product prices with 3 decimals - and all other prices (subtotal, total, tax) should be with 2 decimals (rounded) - also in the e-mails this prices should have 2 decimals.
is there a simple function for this or a work around? Thanks for the help!
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

) Just found a way and wanted to share with you:
Select in the woocommerce settings the 2 decimals for the shop.
then add this to the function.php of your theme:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals' , 'custom_price_decimals', 20, 1 );
function custom_price_decimals( $decimals ) {
if( is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) 
    $decimals = 3;

return $decimals;
}
```